# Запуск кода Python через терминал. Ошибка No such file or directory

Tags: python, консоль

Запускаю консольный файловый менеджер, терминал выдает ошибку - не найден нужный файл.

Проверяю через ранер Pycharm'a через  `os.getcwd()`, показывает нужную директорию, ту, в которой находится файл с кодом. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]При запуске терминала он указывает совсем другой путь. В чем проблема?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Запуск запуск в командной строке и через PyCharm это два разных процесса (непохожих снаружи, внутри-то там одно и то же).

В первом случае запускается исполняемый интерпретатор python, который находится где-то в служебных папках, который ищет переданый ему аргументом файл. В вашем случае передано `main.py`. Путь относительный и очевидно, что в папке с интерпретатором такого файла нет. Потому и выдается ошибка.

В запуске через PyCharm тоже запускается инерпретатор (системый или пичарный, сейчас неважно) и ему ***неявно*** передается путь до запускаемого скрипта.

Т.е. в первом случае вы запускаете

```
/какаято/папка/на/системном/диске/python main.py
```

а во втором случае

```
/какаято/папка/на/системном/диске/python /полный/путь/до/файла/main.py
```

Поэтому при запуске через консоль нужно или предварительно перейти в папку с файлом, или указываеть полный путь до файла.

А `os.getcwd()` вам покажет ту папку, в которой находится скрипт. Но выполняется-то у вас не скрипт, а интерпретатор и рабочая директория у него совсем другая. Запустите файл где написано

```
import os
os.getcwd()
```

и эти же две строчки просто в интерпретаторе питона. Результаты будут разные.

Answer (score 1):

Вообще-то каталоги запуска и терминала, и "ранера" в PyCharm настраиваются, но чтобы минимизировать проблемы, можете искать файл относительно файла с текстом программы, т.е. для данных в том же каталоге можно использовать `pathlib.Path(__file__).parent / 'my_data_file.txt'`. Тем более, при вызове "без PyCharm" (из командной строки) текущий каталог тоже може быть где угодно.

Могут быть тонкости при упаковке программы в один исполняемый файл (не проверял).

Ну а еще разумнее файл данных передать в параметрах командной строки.